# copy data from one table to another table with defferent column

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I create a table but when i try to get data from it I find many probleme so I create another table and i try to cpy the column t1m1 and t1m2 from the first table into column loc_awa from the 2nd table and separate them with a '_' and rt1m1 rt1m2 into score and so on
but when i run the php page i get this error

> "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'match VALUES
>   ('1','IRT_MAS','2_0')' at line 1' in C:\wamp\www\fantasy\temp.php on
>   line 19"

--Table1--

```html
--Table1--
<style type="text/css">
 table.tableizer-table {
 border: 1px solid #CCC; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 12px;
} 
.tableizer-table td {
 padding: 4px;
 margin: 3px;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.tableizer-table th {
 background-color: #104E8B; 
 color: #FFF;
 font-weight: bold;
}
</style><table class="tableizer-table">
<tr class="tableizer-firstrow"><th>jawla_id Croissant </th><th>m1t1 </th><th>rm1t1 </th><th>m1t2 </th><th>rm1t2 </th><th>m2t1 </th><th>rm2t1 </th><th>m2t2 </th><th>rm2t2 </th><th>m3t1 </th><th>rm3t1 </th><th>m3t2 </th><th>rm3t2 </th><th>m4t1 </th><th>rm4t1 </th><th>m4t2 </th><th>rm4t2 </th><th>m5t1 </th><th>rm5t1 </th><th>m5t2 </th><th>rm5t2 </th><th>m6t1 </th><th>rm6t1 </th><th>m6t2 </th><th>rm6t2 </th><th>m7t1 </th><th>rm7t1 </th><th>m7t2 </th><th>rm7t2 </th><th>m8t1 </th><th>rm8t1 </th><th>m8t2 </th><th>rm8t2</th></tr>
 <tr><td>1 </td><td>IRT </td><td>2 </td><td>MAS </td><td>0 </td><td>KAC </td><td>0 </td><td>DHJ </td><td>0 </td><td>FUS </td><td>2 </td><td>RCA </td><td>0 </td><td>WAC </td><td>4 </td><td>FAR </td><td>2 </td><td>RSB </td><td>0 </td><td>OCK </td><td>0 </td><td>HUSA </td><td>2 </td><td>CRA </td><td>1 </td><td>KACM </td><td>2 </td><td>MCO </td><td>0 </td><td>OCS </td><td>1 </td><td>MAT </td><td>0</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2 </td><td>CRA </td><td>1 </td><td>IRT </td><td>0 </td><td>RCA </td><td>1 </td><td>KACM </td><td>1 </td><td>MAS </td><td>1 </td><td>FUS </td><td>1 </td><td>FAR </td><td>1 </td><td>OCS </td><td>1 </td><td>MCO </td><td>1 </td><td>KAC </td><td>0 </td><td>DHJ </td><td>0 </td><td>RSB </td><td>1 </td><td>OCK </td><td>1 </td><td>WAC </td><td>3 </td><td>MAT </td><td>2 </td><td>HUSA </td><td>4</td></tr>
 <tr><td>3 </td><td>OCS </td><td>0 </td><td>OCK </td><td>1 </td><td>IRT </td><td>2 </td><td>MAT </td><td>2 </td><td>KACM </td><td>0 </td><td>MAS </td><td>0 </td><td>FUS </td><td>1 </td><td>CRA </td><td>1 </td><td>KAC </td><td>1 </td><td>RSB </td><td>2 </td><td>MCO </td><td>0 </td><td>RCA </td><td>1 </td><td>WAC </td><td>2 </td><td>DHJ </td><td>1 </td><td>HUSA </td><td>1 </td><td>FAR </td><td>0</td></tr>
 <tr><td>4 </td><td>MAT </td><td>0 </td><td>FUS </td><td>3 </td><td>RCA </td><td>0 </td><td>KAC </td><td>1 </td><td>CRA </td><td>1 </td><td>KACM </td><td>0 </td><td>MAS </td><td>1 </td><td>MCO </td><td>2 </td><td>FAR </td><td>1 </td><td>IRT </td><td>2 </td><td>DHJ </td><td>0 </td><td>OCS </td><td>0 </td><td>OCK </td><td>2 </td><td>HUSA </td><td>1 </td><td>RSB </td><td>0 </td><td>WAC </td><td>0</td></tr>
 <tr><td>5 </td><td>IRT </td><td>2 </td><td>OCK </td><td>1 </td><td>KACM </td><td>2 </td><td>MAT </td><td>1 </td><td>FUS </td><td>2 </td><td>FAR </td><td>3 </td><td>RCA </td><td>3 </td><td>MAS </td><td>0 </td><td>KAC </td><td>0 </td><td>WAC </td><td>1 </td><td>HUSA </td><td>1 </td><td>DHJ </td><td>1 </td><td>MCO </td><td>2 </td><td>CRA </td><td>3 </td><td>OCS </td><td>1 </td><td>RSB </td><td>0</td></tr>
 <tr><td>6 </td><td>RSB </td><td>1 </td><td>HUSA </td><td>1 </td><td>FAR </td><td>1 </td><td>KACM </td><td>0 </td><td>DHJ </td><td>1 </td><td>IRT </td><td>1 </td><td>OCK </td><td>1 </td><td>FUS </td><td>2 </td><td>WAC </td><td>2 </td><td>OCS </td><td>0 </td><td>MAS </td><td>0 </td><td>KAC </td><td>0 </td><td>CRA </td><td>0 </td><td>RCA </td><td>2 </td><td>MAT </td><td>1 </td><td>MCO </td><td>1</td></tr>
 <tr><td>7 </td><td>IRT </td><td>1 </td><td>RSB </td><td>0 </td><td>KACM </td><td>1 </td><td>OCK </td><td>0 </td><td>FUS </td><td>0 </td><td>DHJ </td><td>0 </td><td>MCO </td><td>0 </td><td>FAR </td><td>0 </td><td>KAC </td><td>2 </td><td>OCS </td><td>1 </td><td>MAS </td><td>1 </td><td>CRA </td><td>0 </td><td>RCA </td><td>2 </td><td>MAT </td><td>3 </td><td>HUSA </td><td>0 </td><td>WAC </td><td>1</td></tr>
 <tr><td>8 </td><td>CRA </td><td>1 </td><td>KAC </td><td>2 </td><td>OCS </td><td>2 </td><td>HUSA </td><td>4 </td><td>DHJ </td><td>1 </td><td>KACM </td><td>0 </td><td>WAC </td><td>2 </td><td>IRT </td><td>2 </td><td>FAR </td><td>1 </td><td>RCA </td><td>0 </td><td>MAT </td><td>1 </td><td>MAS </td><td>0 </td><td>OCK </td><td>1 </td><td>MCO </td><td>2 </td><td>RSB </td><td>0 </td><td>FUS </td><td>1</td></tr>
 <tr><td>9 </td><td>CRA </td><td>1 </td><td>MAT </td><td>2 </td><td>IRT </td><td>0 </td><td>OCS </td><td>1 </td><td>KACM </td><td>0 </td><td>RSB </td><td>0 </td><td>KAC </td><td>3 </td><td>HUSA </td><td>1 </td><td>FUS </td><td>1 </td><td>WAC </td><td>0 </td><td>RCA </td><td>1 </td><td>OCK </td><td>2 </td><td>MAS </td><td>0 </td><td>FAR </td><td>1 </td><td>MCO </td><td>1 </td><td>DHJ </td><td>0</td></tr>
 <tr><td>10 </td><td>HUSA </td><td>1 </td><td>IRT </td><td>3 </td><td>FAR </td><td>2 </td><td>CRA </td><td>2 </td><td>WAC </td><td>2 </td><td>KACM </td><td>0 </td><td>DHJ </td><td>1 </td><td>RCA </td><td>1 </td><td>OCK </td><td>0 </td><td>MAS </td><td>3 </td><td>RSB </td><td>2 </td><td>MCO </td><td>1 </td><td>MAT </td><td>1 </td><td>KAC </td><td>0 </td><td>OCS </td><td>0 </td><td>FUS </td><td>1</td></tr>
 <tr><td>11 </td><td>MAS </td><td>0 </td><td>DHJ </td><td>0 </td><td>MCO </td><td>1 </td><td>WAC </td><td>1 </td><td>MAT </td><td>1 </td><td>FAR </td><td>1 </td><td>RCA </td><td>1 </td><td>RSB </td><td>0 </td><td>CRA </td><td>1 </td><td>OCK </td><td>0 </td><td>KAC </td><td>0 </td><td>IRT </td><td>0 </td><td>KACM </td><td>1 </td><td>OCS </td><td>2 </td><td>FUS </td><td>2 </td><td>HUSA </td><td>0</td></tr>
</table>
```

--Table 2--
jawla_id           loc_awa         score
Here's the code that i use :

```
<?php
try{
        $host="localhost";
        $datab="nmdatab";
        $user="user";
        $pass="password";
        $conect=new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$datab",$user,$pass);
        $conect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
    catch(Exception $e){
        die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
    }
    $matche=$conect->query('SELECT * FROM jawlat ORDER BY jawla_id');
        while ($mt=$matche->fetch()){
            $jawla_id="".$mt["jawla_id"]."";
            $match="".$mt["m1t1"]."_".$mt["m1t2"]."";
            $score="".$mt["rm1t1"]."_".$mt["rm1t2"]."";
            $nt="INSERT INTO match VALUES ('$jawla_id','$match','$score')";
            $conect->exec($nt);
            $match="".$mt["m2t1"]."_".$mt["m2t2"]."";
            $score="".$mt["rm2t1"]."_".$mt["rm2t2"]."";
            $nt="INSERT INTO match  VALUES ('$jawla_id','$match','$score')";
            $conect->exec($nt);
            $match="".$mt["m3t1"]."_".$mt["m3t2"]."";
            $score="".$mt["rm3t1"]."_".$mt["rm3t2"]."";
            $nt="INSERT INTO match  VALUES ('$jawla_id','$match','$score')";
            $conect->exec($nt);
            $match="".$mt["m4t1"]."_".$mt["m4t2"]."";
            $score="".$mt["rm4t1"]."_".$mt["rm4t2"]."";
            $nt="INSERT INTO match  VALUES ('$jawla_id','$match','$score')";
            $conect->exec($nt);
            $match="".$mt["m5t1"]."_".$mt["m5t2"]."";
            $score="".$mt["rm5t1"]."_".$mt["rm5t2"]."";
            $nt="INSERT INTO match  VALUES ('$jawla_id','$match','$score')";
            $conect->exec($nt);
            $match="".$mt["m5t1"]."_".$mt["m5t2"]."";
            $score="".$mt["rm5t1"]."_".$mt["rm5t2"]."";
            $nt="INSERT INTO match  VALUES ('$jawla_id','$match','$score')";
            $conect->exec($nt);
            $match="".$mt["m5t1"]."_".$mt["m5t2"]."";
            $score="".$mt["rm5t1"]."_".$mt["rm5t2"]."";
            $nt="INSERT INTO match  VALUES ('$jawla_id','$match','$score')";
            $conect->exec($nt);
            $match="".$mt["m5t1"]."_".$mt["m5t2"]."";
            $score="".$mt["rm5t1"]."_".$mt["rm5t2"]."";
            $nt="INSERT INTO match  VALUES ('$jawla_id','$match','$score')";
            $conect->exec($nt);
            echo "jawla ".$jawla." done";
        }
```

?>

Comment: Not sure what `Sql Server` tag is doing here. Removed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Match is a [**reserved**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html) keyword you need to escape it using `back-ticks`

```
INSERT INTO `match`(col1,col2,col3)  
         VALUES ('$jawla_id','$match','$score')
```